# How do I install modelsim6.5f?

Tags: software-installation

the following errors are occuring while installing modelsim6.5f in ubuntu11.10

```
sudo apt-get install install.linux
```

Which results in

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package install.linux
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'install.linux'
```

Comment: if you could give us the file contents then we can help us .Actually i think you have downloaded the source package . so tell us what are the contents of that file and one more thing is look for README or INSTALL file in that , those gonna have installation instructions .

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've downloaded it legally, then install.linux is probably a script you have to run which self-extracts and runs an installer. It doesn't look like they provide a debian package which you would install with dpkg, and modelsim not being free/open source software, is not available in the Ubuntu archives, so apt-get install won't work to install it. You probably need to do the following:

```
chmod +x install.linux
sudo ./install.linux
```